# How to fix VueColor is not defined error with xiaokaike/vue-color component

Tags: vuejs2, color-picker

In laravel 5.7/Vuejs 2.6 app I want to add https://github.com/xiaokaike/vue-color component and to use it as color picker and googling 
I found this https://codepen.io/Brownsugar/pen/NaGPKy example, but trying to use it in my component I got error :

```
app.js?dt=1556192237:3726 Uncaught ReferenceError: VueColor is not defined
    at Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./resources/js/components/BS4/Personal.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js?dt=1556192237:3726)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js?dt=1556192237:20)
    at Module../resources/js/components/BS4/Personal.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js?dt=1556192237:112840)
```

In my component I did as :

```
<script>
    import {bus} from '../../app';
    import appMixin from '../../appMixin';
//    import 'vue-color';   // I Tried to uncomment these 2 lines - but the same error anyway.
//    import 'vue-color/dist/vue-color';

    import Vue from 'vue';
    import vSelect from 'vue-select'
    Vue.component('v-select', vSelect)
    import { compact } from 'vue-color' ;
    var Chrome = VueColor.Chrome;
    Vue.component('colorpicker', {
        components: {
            'chrome-picker': Chrome,
        }
    });

    export default {
        name: "Personal",
        components: {
        },
        data() {
```

In my package.json :

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.4.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.15",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.2",
        "sass": "^1.19.0",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.10",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jquery-confirm": "^3.3.4",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.5.3",
        "marked": "^0.6.2",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "pusher-js": "^4.4.0",
        "vee-validate": "^2.2.3",
        "vee-validate-laravel": "^1.1.0",
        "vue-color": "^2.7.0",
        "vue-moment": "^4.0.0",
        "vue-notification": "^1.3.16",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.6",
        "vue-select": "^2.6.4",
        "vuex": "^3.1.0"
    }
}


How to fix it ?
```

**Modified Block :**
I saw this example, but it looks different as below :
https://prnt.sc/nh62je
and compact a top of the printscreen
I need like at url https://codepen.io/Brownsugar/pen/NaGPKy 
and looking atthis sample I miss where VueColor is defined in this working example...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

But your import statement seems to be missing a variable name, see this example from the docs. Here they import a picker named `Photoshop`

```
import { Photoshop } from 'vue-color'

new Vue({
    components: {
      'photoshop-picker': Photoshop
    }
})
```

Comment: Please look at Modified Block